# Fixed size of arrowhead for any line weight in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to keep the size of an arrowhead independent of the weight of the line it is attached to?

I'd like to fix the arrowhead at a particular size, and from then on adjust line weight without it changing the arrow size. Open to any method that achieves this!

Answer (score 1):

You could click *Object > Expand Appearance*, then select the stroke using the direct selection tool (A), then change the stroke size. Obviously once separated from the stroke the arrow head will no longer automatically be attached to the end of the stroke. So, if you move the end, you need to reposition the arrow head manually.

[image]

It's also possible to mess around with the scale factor of the arrow head, but it's probably just as cumbersome TBH.

Comment: Thanks yes, so far the best I have is to create the line _without_ an arrow, and have the arrowhead placed over it as a separate object.